# Send message to phone number in xcode when the user click on submit button in a view

Tags: iphone

I have a view ,It is having the textfield and submit button. After  enter the phone number in textfield user clicks on the submit button.Then I need to send the message to the phone number without opening the mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller.Let me know if you need any more details.Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 @sosborn, i really hope they'd read the XCode tag description too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to open `MFMessageComposeViewController` then I would suggest you use clickatell.com sms gateway to send sms. You can implement their api on your server and hit a web service on your server when you want to send a sms.

But the thing is you have to pay for every sms user send. Where as if you open `MFMessageComposeViewController` user pays for that sms.

Comment: I am glad I could help.. don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you think it helps you